# Does invoking two concurrent mains of the same class influence its own static variables?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, httpserver, executor

i'm building a HTTP Server ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html)) and i'm using

```
 Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
```

to awswer my requests. The handler that resolves such requests runs the following code:

```
  IntFactorization.main(input);
```

where IntFactorization is an instrumented class in such way that I have to mandatorily use the main method. The instrumentation class has all of this methods and attributes as static. Its methods are also synchronized.

The main of IntFactorization is like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

IntFactorization obj = new IntFactorization();

int i = 0;



System.out.println("Factoring " + args[0] + "...");

ArrayList<BigInteger> factors = 

  obj.calcPrimeFactors(new BigInteger(args[0]));

System.out.println("");

System.out.print("The prime factors of " + args[0] + " are ");



for (BigInteger bi: factors) {

  i++;

  System.out.print(bi.toString());

  if (i == factors.size()) {

    System.out.println(".");

  } else {

    System.out.print(", ");

  }

}





System.out.println("");

}
```

My server has to awswer multiple requests concurrently and as we set server executor to

```
 Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

However, analysing the results I noticed that for the same number, the result of its factorization is not always the same. 
I think it might be (but I would like for you to confirm) that the fact of the code being instrumentated with static variables mean that if a server runs two executors then the threads are influencing one another?

Comment: I don't see static variables used in this code.

Comment: @RealSkeptic this code is the original non-instrumented one. The static variables are added by the instrumentation class along with the calls to syncronized static methods

Comment: There is only a single instance of `static` variables in a class. So if two different threads access a static variable (threading issues aside), they will influence each other. This may or may not be what is desired. If one wanted to, e.g., count the number of threads created, then a static variable would be useful. If each instantiated object needs its own measurement variables, then static counters would likely not be appropriate.

Comment: @KevinO The purpose of the instrumentation is to see the number of times a given instruction is executed in each execution. So i guess it won't work..

Comment: Well, unless you show us what the code looks like after instrumentation, or an equivalent, it's hard to know what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the bit about an "instrumentation class", but the title of your question is interesting.

> [Does invoking two concurrent mains of the same class influence its own static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37216381/does-invoking-two-concurrent-mains-of-the-same-class-influence-its-own-static-va)

There's nothing special about a `public static void main(String[] args)` method in the Java language.

A standard *JVM* will call the method with that name and argument signature if you give the name of its class on the JVM command line, but that's the JVM.  That's not Java.

Apart from `main(...)` being useable as an entry point for an application, it is otherwise just like any other static method.  It will "influence" the static variables of its class (or, of any other class) if that's what it was written to do.  If two or more threads make overlapped calls to `main()` at the same time, that's just like two or more threads making overlapped calls to *any* method at the same time.

Comment: even though the methods that i use for altering the static variables being all synchronized? An instrumentation class is a class that instruments a piece of code ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_%28computer_programming%29))

Comment: @user2934164, I don't understand what you are asking.  You say there are some static variables (not shown in your code snippet.)  You say that two threads call a method named `main()`.  You _don't_ say how main() (or anything that could be called within main()) _uses_ those variables.  If two threads use the same variables, then of course they can "influence" each other.  Adding `synchronized` probably won't change that, but `synchronized` (if you use it right) _might_ prevent the interacting threads from putting _intentionally_ shared data into some "corrupt" or "invalid" state.

Comment: ok I thinked I got the answer. guess I have to change the architecture of my solution